# How to get data as associative array using find all in cakephp 3 ?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.x

I have a table call users , I have tried below code

```
$query = $this->Users->find('all',['conditions' => ['users.id' => 1]]);
$data = $query->toArray();

foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
          echo $value;
}
```

I have got output like

```
{ "id": 1, "username": "admin", "image": "", "created": "2016-05-11T06:52:59+0000" }
```

I need the array like

```
["0": 1, "1": "admin", "2": "", "3": "2016-05-11T06:52:59+0000"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simply use [hydrate](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#getting-arrays-instead-of-entities)

```
$query->hydrate(false);
$data = $query->toArray();
```

then you'll have an associative array instead of an object

then if you actually want an indexed array you can simply do

```
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    debug(array_values($value));
}
```